# Failed to install apk on device 'emulator-5554': No such file or directory

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

Yes there are several other questions on SO like this, I've tried what is suggested there, to no avail. Note that I am trying to run an emulator here, not an actual device.

I have set the Run Configuration to Always prompt to pick device. Then I do `Run as > Android Application`, then selected emulator, then waited for it (until AVD Name appears)

```
[HelloWorld] New emulator found: emulator-5554  
[HelloWorld] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...  
[HelloWorld] ------------------------------  
[HelloWorld] Android Launch!  
[HelloWorld] adb is running normally.  
[HelloWorld] Performing com.mkyong.android.HelloWorldActivity activity
```

launch
    [HelloWorld] Uploading HelloWorld.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'

Then did Run as > Android Application and selected the running emulator-5554, which gives the error:

```
[HelloWorld] Failed to install HelloWorld.apk on device 'emulator-5554': No such file or directory
[HelloWorld] com.android.ddmlib.SyncException: No such file or directory
[HelloWorld] Launch canceled!
```

I have tried the following repeating the above steps afterward:

Deleted bin and gen folders, then did Clean

I went into DDMS and did Reset adb. then did Run as > Android Application and selected the running emulator-5554 with the same result.

Changed the ADB connection timeout from  5000ms to 10000ms
    Window -> Preferences -> Android -> DDMS -> ADB Connection Timeout (ms)

Opened task manager, end the task named "adb" then restarted eclipse. Then Project Clean.

Closed the project, Closed Eclipse, then Restarted Eclipse and opened project

Started emulator independent of the project via Android Virtual Device Manager > Start > Launch
This results in the emulator window being displayed, but contains nothing (completely black)
and another window saying:
    Starting emulator for AVD ''
    emulator: warning: opening audio input failed
And it remains this way. Even clicking Cancel does nothing.

I went inot the Android Virtual Device Manager > Android Virtual Devices, then 
Select a device, Edit. In the Device pull down, select a device if one is not selected Memory Options: RAM 768. Then Start > Launch, The Emulator window comes up. "Android" is displayed in the window.LogCat shows lots of stuff, this seems significant:

```
Failed to connect to host (QemuPipeStream)!!!  
E/EGL_emulation(420): Failed to establish connection with the host
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you using AndroidStudio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe check you have the relevant SDKs installed for the API of the emulator?

Windows -> Android SDK manager

Shot in the dark from me.

Comment: This is effectively the answer. I am unable to install the necessary SDK because of version conflicts. So I had to get the latest version of Eclipse and add the ADT Plugin.